# PyTorch how to implement disconnection (connections and corresponding gradients are masked)?

Tags: python, neural-network, pytorch

I try to implement the following graph. As you can see, the neurons are not fully connected, i.e., the weights are masked and so are their corresponding gradients.

[image]

```
import torch
import numpy as np

x = torch.rand((3, 1))
# tensor([[ 0.8525],
#         [ 0.1509],
#         [ 0.9724]])

weights = torch.rand((2, 3), requires_grad=True)
# tensor([[ 0.3240,  0.0792,  0.6858],
#         [ 0.5248,  0.4565,  0.3625]])

mask = torch.Tensor([[0,1,0],[1,0,1]])
# tensor([[ 0.,  1.,  0.],
#         [ 1.,  0.,  1.]])

mask_weights = weights * mask
# tensor([[ 0.0000,  0.0792,  0.0000],
#         [ 0.5248,  0.0000,  0.3625]])

y = torch.mm(mask_weights, x)
# tensor([[ 0.0120],
#         [ 0.7999]])
```

This question is originally posted at [Pytorch Forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/weights-disconnection-implementation/19314). Note the above way

> mask_weights = weights * mask

is **NOT** suitable since corresponding gradients are not 0.

Is there an elegant way to do that please?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, the above method is correct. **The disconnections essentially block feed-forward and back-propogation on corresponding connections.** In other words, weights and gradients are masked. The codes in question reveal the first while this answer reveals the latter.

```
mask_weights.register_hook(print)

z = torch.Tensor([[1], [1]])
# tensor([[ 1.],
#         [ 1.]])

out = (y-z).mean()
# tensor(-0.6595)

out.backward()
# tensor([[ 0.1920,  0.1757,  0.0046],
#         [ 0.1920,  0.1757,  0.0046]])

weights.grad
# tensor([[ 0.0000,  0.1757,  0.0000],
#         [ 0.1920,  0.0000,  0.0046]])
```

As you can see, the gradients of weights are masked automatically.